# Convergence of $\sum\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\tan\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This questian I encountered in a book named MATHEMATICAL ANALYSIS by Savita Arora  .This comes under convergence test.
$$\sum\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\tan\frac{1}{n}$$ what series must be used to compare this.I used $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ to compare $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\tan\frac{1}{n}$$  So since $\sum\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is divegent so does $\sum\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\tan\frac{1}{n}$but its not the correct answer.What is the criteria to select a sequence to compare it. What is the sequence which must be used in this case

Comment: Note that $\tan x\sim x$ as $x\to0$.

Comment: $$\frac1{\sqrt n}\not<\frac1{\sqrt n}\tan\frac1n$$

Comment: It's not true that $n^{-1/2} < n^{-1/2} \tan n^{-1}$ because $\tan x < 1$ when $x < \arctan 1 = \pi/4$.

Comment: Just over $3.2157$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the limit comparison test. We know that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x}{x}=1.
$$
In particular
$$
1=\lim_{n\to \infty}n\tan (1/n)=
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\tan(1/n)}{\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}}.
$$
Since $3/2>1$ the series converges.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$x<\tan x<\tan(1)x\quad\forall 0<x<1$$

let $x=\frac1n$ and apply the comparison test.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Why?  It yields the following: $$\frac1{n^{3/2}}<\frac1{\sqrt n}\tan\frac1n<\frac{\tan(1)}{n^{3/2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\tan\frac{1}{n}\sim\frac{1}{n^{1.5}}$$ and since $1.5>1$, we are done.